# Primary Server is "Resolving state" & Quorum node is in "failed" state

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups, clustering, windows-server

I would like to say that in my environment I have a 2 node in WSFC with the nodes

```
SQLServer-01 (Primary Server)
SQLServer-02 (Secondary Server)
```

And for third vote in cluster also One (`File share witness`)in quorum & also listener has configured .

I was not a guy who had made the configuration of WSFC , quorum and installation of both SQLServer.

Last Thursday the system administrator guy was updated some widows path and had setup a schedule time to restart the windows server operating systems.

When we came to office as on Sunday. we saw the SQL Server Database engine was stopped in both server as well as quorum was went to in Failed state.

We are able to start the SQL Server engine services in both server. In primary server after connecting with SSMS then find out the `Primary Server` is in `Resolving State` & Secondary is UP state. And Also AlwaysOn Availability Group node is in `Resolving state`. And those databases are participating in AlwaysOn availability group in primary server , which is showing like (`Not synchronizing /Recovery pending`). As you can see the below attachment sheet of SSMS screen shot. which has taken in Primary Server.
[image]

I am also attaching the quorum state 
[image]

and fail over cluster manager screen shot for (cluster node participation) 
[image]

also attaching the screen shot of file share witness from fail over cluster manager window.
[image]

My Question is that in this situation ,

1)how i shall bring back online to my Quorum node.
2)After that how i shall bring back my Primary server from resolving to normal state.

I know that this is a one of the critical situation of troubleshooting in the life of DBA world.
Even i have already went through the MSDN BOL [WSFC Disaster Recovery through Forced Quorum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/wsfc-disaster-recovery-through-forced-quorum-sql-server) and [Perform a Forced Manual Failover of an Availability Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/perform-a-forced-manual-failover-of-an-availability-group-sql-server)
Even as per my DBA knowledge it is only solution through manual fail over to bring back online to quorum node.

Regarding in this regards, any suggestion will be appreciated.

-----After request of @John Eisbrener to upload fail over cluster manager log.
[image]

and

[image]

Comment: What happens when you try to bring your fileshare witness back online?

Comment: Click on the **Recent Cluster Events** link on the *Failover Cluster Manager* window.  That will likely show what's occurring that's preventing a node from coming online.  The view you are showing from the Event Viewer window isn't providing the errors I'm concerned about.

Comment: @John,so sorry for today. I have just left the office today,as per my office time in Qatar . Tomorrow sure I will update to you accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Can you add an answer if this was resolved?